# CountDown Timer in android. Pushing to TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-logcat, countdowntimer

Hi guys I have the code below that is supposed to count down to a certain date but I am getting a `NullPointerException` somewhere in the ontick. Can someone please point out where the problem is? Below is the countdown timer that will display in **MainActivity.java**.

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    long currentTime = gc.getTimeInMillis();
    GregorianCalendar futureDate = new  GregorianCalendar();
    futureDate.set(2015, 10, 14, 0, 0, 0);
    long difference = futureDate.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;

    long x = difference/1000;
    final long second = x % 60;
    x = x/60;
    long minutes = x%60;
    x /= 60;
    long hour = x % 24;
    x /= 24;
    long days = x;
    //end of timer logic to use

    // injecting into the user interface
    timerDays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerday);
    myClock = new CountDownTimer(difference, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            String secs = Long.toString(second);
            timerDays.setText(secs);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timerDays.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
```

The Logcat messages are as follows:

```
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.iantheninja.ndw, PID: 16925
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iantheninja.ndw/com.iantheninja.ndw.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2344)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.iantheninja.ndw.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5279)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324) 
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328) 
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
11-06 15:44:32.915 16925-16925/com.iantheninja.ndw E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What are you trying to display? and does it crash immediately?

Comment: Kindly put the error log from Logcat.

Comment: Have you checked R.id.timerday is correct? May be  timerDays is null

Comment: what is line MainActivity.java:55

Comment: @UdiIdan Yes it does. And There goes the logcat Darwin

Comment: @iantheninja LogCat says you are trying to start MainActivity, but there is a NullPointerException here. I don't think your code crashes when the timer ticking. Which line do you trying to start a new Activity?

Comment: Have you called setContentView before that code?

Comment: Show us more code - onCreate and the XML, and it will be much easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
timerDays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerday);
```

You may have no View has the id `R.id.timerday`.

Comment: Is it  timerDays = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerday) the line55?Try to   parse the xml you setContentView().It's best if you can provoide complete code of Activity and layout.